# Formatting output in fprintf

Tags: c, formatting, string-formatting

Thanks to your assistance earlier I was able to write a program that generates SHA 512 and MD5 hashes from text in a text file and place the output hashes in a seperate text file. I am very much grateful for that.
The program is as follows :

File-name: hashgen.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main (){

    // Start : Display the time of starting the program
    time_t starttime;
    struct tm * starttimeinfo;

    time ( &starttime );
    starttimeinfo = localtime ( &starttime );
    printf ( "Program Started At: %s", asctime (starttimeinfo) );
        //declaring a file to be selected by user
    FILE *user_file;
    char buf[1000];

    FILE *resultfile;
    resultfile = fopen("mytab2411.txt","w");


    // md5 hash
    char * hash_md5 = "$1$";
    // sha512 hash
    char * hash_sha = "$6$";

    //Specify Salt   
    char * salt_1 ="$";     
    char * result;
    char encyption_scheme[20];
    char userfilename[128];

    //Prompt to enter file name
     printf("Enter a file name\n");
     scanf("%123s",userfilename);

    //opening the file  
    user_file=fopen(userfilename,"r"); 
    //Error if file does not exist
    if (!user_file){
        printf("Could not find file: %123s",userfilename);
        printf("Please verify the file path");


        time_t exittime1;
        struct tm *exittimeinfo1;

        time ( &exittime1 );
        exittimeinfo1 = localtime ( &exittime1 );


        printf ( "Program Ended At: %s", asctime (exittimeinfo1) );
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        //reading from file
        while (fgets(buf,1000, user_file)!=NULL){

        /* hashing using md5 */

            strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_md5);
            strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
            result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
            fprintf(resultfile,"%s",buf);
            fprintf(resultfile,"%s",result);

             /* hashing using sha-512 */ 
             strcpy(encyption_scheme,hash_sha);
             strcat(encyption_scheme,salt_1);
             result = crypt(buf,encyption_scheme);
            fprintf(resultfile,"%s",buf);

            fprintf(resultfile,"%s",result);
            }
            //closing file
            fclose(resultfile);
            //display time program ended
            time_t endtime;
            struct tm * endtimeinfo;

            time ( &endtime );
            endtimeinfo = localtime ( &endtime );


            printf ( "Program Ended At: %s", asctime (endtimeinfo) );

}
```

The text file used contained the following words:

File-name: Sample.txt

```
John
Paul
Ringo
George
```

Now, the hash values of the words in Sample.txt are stored in mytab2411.txt. The file appears as such.

File-name : mytab2411.txt

```
John
$1$$l1fRKKtYSfJOVyWKw3rFH1John
$6$$9s3dCSxRBiVAzeBQR.bJLGdPL6VhH4p7fJu2aiaOLxcS4wLpWifoWNxTtaOQGnIHOZadh5rHhuuOOHEicLCV20Paul
$1$$.NeC/EbTUibao2by.HNV01Paul
$6$$qQs5aHFZX/2Iaz4Y1RIihRn./AszpUZnDfld0h5mrWEtAqRJPanIO3cpT3TOOKuFS5hpmLrKAb5MY2mGV2ato1Ringo
$1$$CfsqYxqUQM5x0o.sjBMjV/Ringo
$6$$iC4vLpyDb5gAw5b7roT79LxiEd3d4LTyi5ftrWW6mwyYHNHenMiaFav4wLR3Rnmut.gJfMHn.Zy.pki9.0OBb.George
$1$$2ij/IqfPsZDlXFUEX7H82/George
$6$$ixjdlMMt3jg1Yb6x91HpVmV3pc9q5o8xFwejxiIyU9yZAoSsiA6qBRuHYInPyQlP4XkrnhuIyUsryLfgtldO5/
```

I would like to use fprintf to ensure that the hash values and the original corresponding words are aligned together. For instance :

File-name : mytab2411.txt

```
John $1$$l1fRKKtYSfJOVyWKw3rFH1    
John $6$$9s3dCSxRBiVAzeBQR.bJLGdPL6VhH4p7fJu2aiaOLxcS4wLpWifoWNxTtaOQGnIHOZadh5rHhuuOOHEicLCV20
Paul $1$$.NeC/EbTUibao2by.HNV01
Paul $6$$qQs5aHFZX/2Iaz4Y1RIihRn./AszpUZnDfld0h5mrWEtAqRJPanIO3cpT3TOOKuFS5hpmLrKAb5MY2mGV2ato1
```

Could someone guide me on how to align the text as seen above using printf ? Thank you.

Comment: You want to print a name and a corresponding hash into each line? What is the problem about that? I.e. what is special about the format you unsuccessfully try to achieve? Guessing the "rule" is hard from the few examples of desired output you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the newline to the format string "%s \n" that will put the name at the beginning on the line if you want the key aligned you can play with \t for tab or adding the specific size to the format string

Comment: Hello ! I have followed your advice and I've come up with this                        fprintf(resultfile,"%-8s %8s\n",buf, result);                                                                  However, it remains misaligned. Is it possible to pad output in fprintf and move the hash upwards ?

Comment: Can you paste in what you have now ? It is possible to make the first column a fixed size and add a tab in between the two strings

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. Are you referring to my fprintf statements or my output in the mytab2411.txt file ?

Comment: Hi,

printf( "%s\t%s\n", pchName, pchHash);

gave this 

Ringo $1$$l1fRKKtYSfJOVyWKw3rFH1
Ringo $6$$9s3dCSxRBiVAzeBQR.bJLGdPL6VhH4p7fJu2aiaOLxcS4wLpWifoWNxTtaOQGnIHOZadh5rHhuuOOHEicLCV20
George $1$$l1fRKKtYSfJOVyWKw3rFH1
George $6$$9s3dCSxRBiVAzeBQR.bJLGdPL6VhH4p7fJu2aiaOLxcS4wLpWifoWNxTtaOQGnIHOZadh5rHhuuOOHEicLCV20
Paul $1$$l1fRKKtYSfJOVyWKw3rFH1
Paul $6$$9s3dCSxRBiVAzeBQR.bJLGdPL6VhH4p7fJu2aiaOLxcS4wLpWifoWNxTtaOQGnIHOZadh5rHhuuOOHEicLCV20
Ringo $1$$l1fRKKtYSfJOVyWKw3rFH1
Ringo $6$$9s3dCSxRBiVAzeBQR.bJLGdPL6VhH4p7fJu2aiaOLxcS4wLpWifoWNxTtaOQGnIHOZadh5rHhuuOOHEicLCV20

Comment: which matches what I think your asking for in a terminal